# Moq - Cannot convert from IGenericRepository To Generic Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please forgive me in advance, I'm trying to learn unit testing and Moq.

I think i've almost managed to set things up properly (but i could be wrong). When i execute the test below i get the following error:

> Cannot convert from
>   'TestMoq.DAL.IGenericRepository' to
>   'TestMoq.DAL.GenericRepository'    TestMoq.UnitTests

On this line:

```
    _mockUnitWork.Setup(m => m.CreditRepository).Returns(_mockRepository.Object);
```

Here's my code:

MoqTest

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TestMoq.Controllers;
using TestMoq.Models;
using TestMoq.DAL;
using Moq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestMoq.UnitTests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class BaseControllerTests
    {

        private Mock<IGenericRepository<Credit>> _mockRepository;
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> _mockUnitWork;



        [Test]
        public void MoqTest() {

            _mockRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Credit>>();
            _mockUnitWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            var _service = new CreditsController(_mockUnitWork.Object);

            List<Credit> listCredit= new List<Credit>() {
           new Credit() { CreditId = 1},
           new Credit() { CreditId = 2},
           new Credit() { CreditId = 3 }
          };

            _mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(null, null, "*")).Returns(listCredit);
            _mockUnitWork.Setup(m => m.CreditRepository).Returns(_mockRepository.Object);

            List<Credit> results = _service.GetAll() as List<Credit>;


            Assert.IsNotNull(results);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, results.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

CreditController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestMoq.CustomFilters;
using TestMoq.DAL;
using TestMoq.Models;

namespace TestMoq.Controllers
{
    public class CreditsController : Controller
    {
        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public CreditsController()
        {
            this._unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        }
        public CreditsController(IUnitOfWork _NewUnitOfWork)
        {
            this._unitOfWork = _NewUnitOfWork;
        }       

        public List<Credit> GetAll()
        {
            return _unitOfWork.CreditRepository.Get().ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

GenericRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using TestMoq.Models;

namespace TestMoq.DAL
{

    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal TcpContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(TcpContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

IGenericRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestMoq.DAL
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        void Delete(object id);
        void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");
        TEntity GetByID(object id);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TestMoq.Models;

namespace TestMoq.DAL
{

    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
    {
        private TcpContext context = new TcpContext();
        public GenericRepository<Credit> creditRepository;

        //Other models & methods removed for clarity


        public GenericRepository<Credit> CreditRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.creditRepository == null)
                {
                    this.creditRepository = new GenericRepository<Credit>(context);
                }

                return creditRepository;
            }

        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
using TestMoq.Models;

namespace TestMoq.DAL
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        GenericRepository<Amendment> AmendmentRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<Credit> CreditRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<FileUpload> FileUploadRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<Job> JobRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<Subscription> SubscriptionRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<Topic> TopicRepository { get; }
        GenericRepository<Writer> WriterRepository { get; }

        void Dispose();
        void Save();
    }
}
```

Apologies in advance if i'm totally messing this up, if you've noticed any other massive errors in my way of thinking (im still getting my head around all this) please do point them out to me.

Thank you!

Comment: `public GenericRepository<Credit> creditRepository;

        //Other models & methods removed for clarity


        public GenericRepository<Credit> CreditRepository` Did you mean both of those to be `IGenericRepository` instead?

Comment: @mjwills is right on the money with this. Your `IUnitOfWork` should almost certainly be defining the repository properties as their interface type, and not their concrete type. `GenericRepository<>` implementing `IGenericRepository<>` does not mean that `IGenericRepository<>` is a `GenericRepository<>`, hence the conversion error.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to figure it out with that help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only mock Interfaces
in you case you need to return IGenericRepository in your IUnitOfWork.

something like this

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IGenericRepository<Amendment> AmendmentRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Credit> CreditRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<FileUpload> FileUploadRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Job> JobRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Subscription> SubscriptionRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Topic> TopicRepository { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Writer> WriterRepository { get; }

        void Dispose();
        void Save();
    }
```